# jquery timer not working properly in setInterval() when one variable changed

Tags: jquery

i have created this timer which works perfectly until one variable is replaced.

timer is running on 3 different divs. Our business logic is when a someone bids just before the timer ends, the timer should change dynamically which is "remaining + increment time = newtime". i'm storing this new time in a hidden value and as far as i have tested it shows perfect time. the coding for the timer which works is:

```
$(".diffinterval").each(function(){
        var total_lot = $(this).val();
        var count = $(this).closest(".heading").find("#lot_count").val();
        var seconds=parseInt($('#diff'+count).val());



        var countdownTimer = setInterval(function(){



            var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
            var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
            var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
            var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
            var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
            var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
            if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
                remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
            }
            $('#countdown'+count).html(": " + days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + remainingSeconds + "s");
            if (seconds == 0) {
                clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                alert('Bidding Time for the below Lots is Over.');
                location.reload();
            } else {
                newtime--;
            }
        },1000);

    });
```

But im trying to retrieve the dynamic change in that hidden field and calculate the time accordingly. The timer stops. This is the block of code which i'm trying

```
$(".diffinterval").each(function(){
        var total_lot = $(this).val();
        var count = $(this).closest(".heading").find("#lot_count").val();
        var seconds=parseInt($('#diff'+count).val());
        var secondElement=$('#diff'+count);



        var countdownTimer = setInterval(function(){

            var ext_time = parseInt(secondElement.val());
            var newtime;
            if(ext_time > seconds)
            {
                newtime=ext_time;
            }   
            else
            {
                newtime=seconds;
            } 

            var days        = Math.floor(newtime/24/60/60);
            var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((newtime) - (days*86400));
            var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
            var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
            var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
            var remainingSeconds = newtime % 60;
            if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
                remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
            }
            $('#countdown'+count).html(": " + days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + remainingSeconds + "s");
            if (newtime == 0) {
                clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                alert('Bidding Time for the below Lots is Over.');
                location.reload();
            } else {
                newtime--;
            }
        },1000);

    });
```

if i change

```
var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
```

to

```
var remainingSeconds = newtime % 60;
```

The timer stops.

Comment: This is little complex to think, could you please create a working fiddle?

Comment: here is a working fiddle of the code that works. change seconds to newtime and timer stops .https://jsfiddle.net/1ajs9ydm/12/

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle your `ext_time` variable gets reinitialized to the `parseInt(secondElement.val())` on each second in setInterval so it will always be whatever value is set in the HTML element. You must take out the variable initialization statement from the setInterval function. You must also decrement that value (`ext_time`) at the end of the `setInterval` in your if/else statement.

**EDIT**: As per your specific use case I updated the fiddle. I added a flag to check whether ext_time was enabled and also a message to let you know that `ext_time` now replaces the `seconds` timer.

Also please note that `seconds` and `secondElement` are both selecting the same elements value, I'm not sure if this is intended, however, if you want a different starting value for `ext_time` you will need to use a different starting value for `secondElement` variable (ie a different hidden input element with a different value property)

Please check out the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ajs9ydm/68/)

I notice your fiddle isn't exactly the same as the code you posted in your question however the problem lies in the placement of your variable initialization.

Comment: ext_time will update just before timer runs out which should be inside the setInterval() for the timer to dynamically change. Is there any way to  do this.

Comment: @Orisys please check my updated fiddle in the answer